# Plotlegend does not work

Tags: plotting, legending

I am trying to add a legend to a plot, but sometimes it work and sometimes it doesn't work and I don't understand why. For example, when I use the following code, I get as an error "Unknown option PlotLegend".

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegend -> {"sine", "cosine"}]
```

Comment: The option's name is `PlotLegends`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the syntax:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> {"sine", "cosine"}]
```

You forgot 's' in PlotLegends.

Comment: I get the same error both with PlotLegend and PlotLegends. The command PlotLegend exists as well.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PlotLegends/ref/PlotLegend.html

Comment: The point is that with the same code yesterday it was working. Might it be a problem with libraries?

Comment: https://flic.kr/p/rJJRTh You can see window of my Matematica with difference between PlotLegend and PlotLegends. And on the site, which you gave above, write about Needs["PlotLegends`"] and there're red highlighted misspelling https://flic.kr/p/rM2Mwp

Comment: In your case it works. In my case it doesn't work.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8635247/Screenshot%202015-03-24%2019.05.59.pdf

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PlotLegends/tutorial/PlotLegends.html I suppose we use different versions of Mathematica. Try to add this instruction before use Plot: << PlotLegends`

Comment: thanks now it works! It is curious that yesterday it was working without loading the package as well.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Good luck to you!